# не загружается FXML файл после копипаста

Tags: java, javafx

Ситуация странная как по мне, есть проект1 на javaFX, он полностью работает, решил сделать exe-шник, пошел по дороге изучения maven. Гугл посоветовал создать `Maven Archetype quickstart`. После создания архитипа maven (проект2) решил перекинуть свой готовый проект в новый. Естественно пришлось переписать некоторые импорты, т.к. дерево классов немного поменялось, но после того, как ошибки все исправил (все они связаны с неправильными импортами) проект не запустился. Исключения ссылаются на загрузку FXML файла, но путь то правильный, и в FXML файлах я пути к контроллерам скорректировал, и с самими путями к FXML файлам поигрался, не пойму в чем причина, наверняка ошибка глупая, но я ее не вижу, помогите плиз

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at zherikhov.Main.initMenuBar(Main.java:70)
    at zherikhov.Main.start(Main.java:51)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application zherikhov.Main
```

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/fxml/menuBarOverview.fxml"));
            mainWindow = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(mainWindow);
            menuBar.setScene(scene);
            menuBar.show();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: использую сейчас путь - zherikhov/view/fxml/menuBarOverview.fxml
если удерживать Ctrl и кликнуть на menuBarOverview.fxml, то IDE видит файл, и перейдет по нему правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте относительный путь, а пишите с корня

```
/fxml/myFile.fxml
```

Переместите все файлы FXML в папку ресурсов. Мавен не копирует их, потому после запуска они не находятся в каталоге классов. Может и можно его заставить это делать, но я не искал способ